# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined - CKEDITOR

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

When I try to go into my text editor ckeditor is not displayed.
Console give this error:

````
    at new CKEDITOR.style (ckeditor.js:504)
    at t (ckeditor.js:786)
    at Object.init (ckeditor.js:794)
    at Object.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:279)
    at e (ckeditor.js:259)
    at Object.load (ckeditor.js:259)
    at ckeditor.js:279
    at CKEDITOR.resourceManager.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:266)
    at CKEDITOR.resourceManager.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:264)
    at e (ckeditor.js:259)```
````

Comment: please post your code

Comment: This is my ckeditor.js: https://paste.ee/p/0iPwS